# Access TabHost from another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a Tab Host with two Tabs: One for an image gallery and another to open a page. Independently the TabHost works fine but when I want to access it through a previous activity the app crashes. can anyone please tell me what the problem is? Whether I have to add something or what I am doing is wrong. Please do tell me if there is another method. My code is given below:

```
public class DelhimapActivity extends TabActivity{

   TabHost tab;
   Intent intent;
   GridView grid;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.delhimap);
      tab = getTabHost();

      tab.addTab(tab.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Images").setContent(R.id.gridView1));
      tab.addTab(tab.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("About").setContent(intent));
      grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
      grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
      intent.setClass(this, DelhiLay.class);
      startActivity(intent);

      tab.setCurrentTab(0);
   }

}
```

My ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      mContext= c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return mThumbIds.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);            

         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

         //myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));

      } else {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

  // references to our images
  private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ben, R.drawable.brent,
        R.drawable.cean,
        R.drawable.charters,
        R.drawable.lynn,
        R.drawable.mark,
        R.drawable.paul,
        R.drawable.philip
  };
}
```

And accessing it from another activity like this:

```
public void onEnter(View v){

      prg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
      Intent inta = new Intent(NewActivity.this,DelhimapActivity.class);
      NewActivity.this.startActivity(inta);
      NewActivity.this.finish();
            }
      },3000
      );
}
```

This is the XML which has the TabHost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:tabStripEnabled="true">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="3" >
            </GridView>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my LogCat for this Activity:

```
08-23 13:56:46.008: E/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**08-23 13:56:46.008: E/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.delhicious.suryastra/com.delhicious.suryastra.DelhimapActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'**
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat!

Comment: This is the error in the Logcat:
08-23 10:19:03.549: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.delhicious.suryastra/com.delhicious.suryastra.DelhimapActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
Have checked but all is fine.

Comment: I posted my XML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `@+id/tabhost` with `@android:id/tabhost` in your layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Download Code example from below link, it may help you.

[Tab Sample](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u66hhp295s5wtjt/Tab_Sample.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the code..but the same thing happens in this one as well. On clicking the TextView the activity crashes rather than going to the Tab page. Could it be my emulator or could I be making a stupid mistake somewhere?